# Angular 2-5 implementation of fullcalender scheduler

Tags: angular, fullcalendar, angular5, fullcalendar-scheduler

I have done a resource scheduling project using full-calendar(fullcalendar.io) plugin with Jquery and html. Now i am converting this project to Angular 5. I tried using few popular angular-full calendar plugins like

```
1.https://github.com/Jamaks/ng-fullcalendar
2.https://github.com/mattlewis92/angular-calendar
3.https://github.com/nekken/ng2-fullcalendar
```

None of the above does not seem be implemented fullcalendar-scheduler also does not support views like 'timelineMonth'.

Please note i have success fully implemeted fullcalendar(https://fullcalendar.io/) in angular but i cant implement(https://fullcalendar.io/scheduler) which is an add-on provided by fullcalender.

Did anyone successfully implemented it? or any plugin suggestion would be a great help.

Answer (score 1):

I've just implemented it this morning. Biggest catch was that you don't need to npm install fullcalendar itself since it is already a dependency of the scheduler. Hope this helps:

**Package.json:**

```
"dependencies": {
  "fullcalendar-scheduler": "^1.9.3",
  "jquery": "^3.3.1",
},
"devDependencies": {
  "@types/jquery": "^3.3.0",
}
```

**Angular-cli.json:**

```
"styles": [
    "styles.css",
    "../node_modules/fullcalendar/dist/fullcalendar.min.css",
    "../node_modules/fullcalendar-scheduler/dist/scheduler.min.css"
  ],
  "scripts": [
    "../node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js",
    "../node_modules/moment/min/moment.min.js",
    "../node_modules/fullcalendar/dist/fullcalendar.min.js",
    "../node_modules/fullcalendar-scheduler/dist/scheduler.min.js"
  ],
```

**Component.ts**

```
import * as $ from 'jquery';
import 'fullcalendar';
import 'fullcalendar-scheduler';

export class CalendarComponent implements AfterViewInit {

    @Input() options;

    @Component({
        selector: 'app-calendar'
    })

    ngAfterViewInit() {
        const containerEl: JQuery = $('app-calendar');
        containerEl.fullCalendar(this.options);
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you sure this works well when the angular event data variable changes?

Comment: Haven't tested that. If you have improvements on the code I can update the answer.

Comment: Do you have a github repository with this project ? Highly interested in seeing it in action.

Comment: @VladN sry, I can't share the project on github.